# Different color cubes in one city

Tags: pandemic

If we had a blue city with one black disease cube due to an outbreak and we pull that blue city card during epidemic infection phase, is it an outbreak? 
We thought that 3 was the max #of cubes one city can have (even if they are of different colors), but I just read one of the thread here that mentioned a city with 2 red cubes and 2 black cubes, total of 4 cubes in one city.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An outbreak only occurs due to cubes of a single color:

> If the city already has 3 cubes **of this color**, do not place a 4th cube. Instead, an outbreak of this disease occurs in the city (see Outbreaks below).

And therefore a city can have up to three cubes of each color, not just three cubes overall:

> As a result of outbreaks, a city may have disease cubes of multiple colors on it; up to 3 cubes of each color. This does not affect infections.

Comment: Thanks Jefromi!! This should help our win% (currently at 20%) lol

Comment: 20%? Ouch! How many Epidemic cards are you putting in the player deck? You might want to take one out just to give you more of a sense of accomplishment :)